# How can i avoid null values from being updating with Realm insertOrUpdate / copyToRealmOrUpdate?

Tags: android, realm

Scenario 1 : I have create Realm Db with Server response(Converting JSON response to list of UserRealmModel with values id(PK) and name) and perform operation copyToRealmOrUpdate(list_of_realmresult). it is working fine first time.

Scenario 2 : Now when i am getting response from server second time i am getting null values for some users and again copyToRealmOrUpdate(list_of_realmresult) operation perform and make those name null for respected id.

Now i want to avoid update operation for those null values which is coming from server side. how can i achieve this with copyToRealmOrUpdate/ insertOrUpdate  method.

Answer (score 3):

`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` overwrites the original object.

You'll have to manage the merge manually yourself.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        UserRealmModel userModel = realm.where(UserRealmModel.class).equalTo("id", id).findOne();
        if(userModel == null) {
            // create and save new
        } else {
            // merge non-null fields
        }
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(userModel);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate these fields with `@Required`.

> **Required fields and null values**
>
> In some cases, null is not an appropriate value of a field. The @Required annotation can be used to tell Realm to enforce checks to disallow null values.

From [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#required-fields-and-null-values).

If you attempt to update a required field with a null value, an exception will be thrown. I don't know by head which one, but I think you can find that out pretty easily.